# ocaml return type. How to know what to write

Tags: function, ocaml

How could I know the type of my function I've just wrote ? What is the rule to apply to know before the type of the function?

i.e i've to write a function of type: (’a -> int) -> ’a -> int -> ’a

Comment: The only way to get a function with that signature is `let f : ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int -> 'a = fun a b c -> b` without some object magic or sideeffects (No way to produce another `'a`), which is probably not what you want. Also can you clarify your question because you asked 2 different ones

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My question was if there is a way to know, starting directly from the type, the function in ocaml. The text of the exercise gives me the type, as in example: write a function with the follows type: 
fun : (’a -> int) -> ’a -> int -> ’a

Is there a general rule to know what function i have to write, even the exercise change?

Answer (score 2):

For rich type systems (I think OCaml may qualify, but I'm not well schooled in type theory) it is undecidable whether there *is* any function of a given type. So there's no formal set of rules in general to produce a function with a given type.

However (IMHO) it's an enjoyable puzzle. It seems to me that if you can understand the type, you're 85% of the way to the solution.

For `('a -> int) -> 'a -> int -> 'a` you can see that it's a function of three parameters that returns something of the same type as the second parameter. Furthermore there is no other information about this type, i.e., the function has to work for any type of second parameter at all. This reduces the number of different possibilities you need to think about.

**Update**

You can work out answers to questions like this using the OCaml toplevel to tell you the types of things. For example, @Artyer's correct answer above would look like this in the toplevel:

```
# let f : ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int -> 'a = fun a b c -> b;;
val f : ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int -> 'a = <fun>
```

It shows that `f` has the desired type.

If you want to get the desired type without ascribing a type yourself, you have to work a little harder. Something like this:

```
# let myfun f a b = if f a + b > 17 then a else a;;
val myfun : ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int -> 'a = <fun>
```

Comment: Ok, Can you write me a general example of function to know the correct answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're asking for. If you want to try out different functions to see what their type is, you can use the OCaml toplevel to tell you. I can add to my answer if you don't already know how to do this.

Comment: No, I've already the ocaml top-level. My question was: in my exam the teacher gives me an exercise as follows: write a function with the follows type: fun..... . I wanted to know if there is a general rule or how to understand, starting from the type, to write the function with the type of fun . (..... Stands for a generic type of an ocaml function)

Comment: There is no general rule, this is the point of my answer. If you understand what the type is telling you, it shouldn't be too hard to write the function for specific cases (especially the ones that appear on exams). I would encourage you just to get comfortable with the types of functions and what they mean. Sorry I can't help more than this.

Answer (score 1):

When you are asked in an exercise to find a value of a given type, the type generally belongs to a quite limited class of types. Typically, the type only contains non-empty base types, arrows, products and free types variables (and divergence is generally not allowed). And in this case, there is a generic algorithm for finding the function. (In other words, propositional calculus is decidable, but indeed determining if a type is inhabited is undecidable in OCaml).

The main idea is to start with the simple realization that finding a value of a base type is trivial.

- If I must find a value of type x:int, I know an answer: 0
- Similarly, If I must find a value of type 'a * 'b, if I already know how to construct both a value x:'a, y:'b then the answer is clearly : `(x, y)`.
- Now let get to the more interesting case; what to do if I am asked to find a function `f: 'a -> 'b`. The simpler case happens if I already know a value of type x:'b, an answer is just: `fun _ -> x`. If I cannot construct such value, then I should use the fact that I am given an argument of type `'a`. The simplest implication form here is that I construct a value of type `'a`. Typically, if I am asked for a function of type 'a -> 'a, the obvious answer is fun x -> x.
  Thus, when trying to find a value of of type `'b`, I should add `'a` to the set of inhabited type that I know, with the value being the function argument. Moreover, if `'a` is a function type and the type of its argument belong to the set of inhabited types, I should add also its application. Similarly, for every function types that I know one inhabitant, I should try to apply it to this new value. I must repeat this recursively, but this should stop because the types are simple.
- The last case is the case for type variables: the answer is then that if I have never found this type variable by exploring the argument of a function types, I cannot build a value of this type. So the answer is that I can only build a value of type equal to a type variable if it is part of the inhabited types that I discovered starting from function arguments.

To summarize, in your example, the algorithm goes like this:

```
f: ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int -> 'a
```

First, the only concrete type that appears is int. So I can just start with the information

```
{ 0 : int } let f: ('a -> int) -> 'a -> int -> 'a
```

Then I asked for a function. So I know that my answer would be of the form

```
let f x = ...
```

Moreover, now I know a value of type x:('a -> int)

```
{ 0:int, x: 'a -> int } let f x: 'a -> int -> 'a
```

The value that I am trying to construct is still a function. So I add a new argument `y` of type `'a`. Moreover I know a value of type `f: 'a -> int`, so I could apply it to the type `'a` and get an int. But I already know an int.
Let's look at the expected result:

```
{ 0:int, x: 'a -> int, y:'a } let f x y : int -> 'a
```

The expected type is still a function type. The new argument type is an int, but I already know how to build an int. Thus, I can just add an argument:

```
{ 0:int, x: 'a -> int, y:'a } let f x y z: 'a
```

This time, the expected type is a type variable `'a`. Since it is a type variable, I need to search if I learnt how to build such type along the way. Here, the answer is yes: the variable y has type `'a`. Thus I know that I can return `y`, and my final function is:

```
let f x y z = y
```

We can try another more complicated example. Can I construct a value of type:
`('a -> 'b) -> ('b-> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c`
Here there is no base type involved. So I don't know how to build any relevant values at the start:

```
{} let f: ('a -> 'b) -> ('b-> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c
```

On the first step, the argument is a function. I have thus learned how to construct: x:('a -> 'b)

```
{ x: 'a -> 'b } let f x : ('b-> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c
```

I still have a function, thus I add another argument

```
{ x: 'a -> 'b, y: 'b -> 'c } let f x y: 'a -> 'c
```

The types are not compatible, so I need to go to the next step. I still have a function, thus this time I learnt how to build an `'a`

```
{ x: 'a -> 'b, y: 'b -> 'c, z:'a } let f x y z:'c
```

But wait I missed the fact that this value of type 'a can be feed to the first argument:

```
{ x: 'a -> 'b, y: 'b -> 'c, z:'a, x z:'b } let f x y z:'c
```

And once I know how to build this value, I can feed it to `y` to get yet another value of type `'c`

```
{ x: 'a -> 'b, y: 'b -> 'c, z:'a, x z:'b, y(x z): 'c } let f x y z:'c
```

Now, there is now more new application left and I must try to find a value of type `'c` in my set of examples. And I have one: `y(x z)`. Thus, one example of function of type: `('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c` is

```ml
let f x y z = y(x z)
```

which is probably more recognizable as

```ml
let reverse_compose f g x = g(f x)
```